# Анимация вращения

Tags: android, android-animation

Хочу чтобы картинка при нажатии на нее имела эффект покачивания (т.е. сначала на 20 градусов влево вращается, затем плавно обратно возвращаясь вращается на -20 градусов и возвращается в начальное положение 0 градусов). Как это сделать?

Я сделал так, но у меня она вращается влево и возвращается обратно на начальную позицию и все

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <rotate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="20" />

    <rotate
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="0" />

    <rotate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="-20" />

    <rotate
        android:duration="1200"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="0" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что все анимации работают одновременно, а должны последовательно. Последнее можно реализовать установив задержку с которой они должны стартовать. Для этого нужен атрибут `android:startOffset`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <rotate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="20" />

    <rotate
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromDegrees="20"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="0" />

    <rotate
        android:startOffset="400"
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="-20" />

    <rotate
        android:startOffset="600"
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromDegrees="-20"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="0" />

</set>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но ваш вариант тоже не совсем как нужно работает. Тоже влево вращается и возвращается на исходную позицию, вправо совсем не вращается

Comment: @MisterX, я скопировал ваш код и добавил только один аттрибут. У вас  2 и 4 анимации вращают от 0 до 0 - в этом проблема. Поправил в ответе

Comment: спасибо. везде в атрибуте android:startOffset значения проставил 100, 200 и 400 плавно вращается.